# An algorithm that creates regular expressions

Tags: regex, algorithm, theory

Is there an algorithm that takes a list of strings and returns the shortest regex true only for those strings?

I'll be a bit specific. I have a list of arbitrary strings that I want to filter (allow null and empty). I also have a list of allowed strings (I allow null and empty). To filter the first list by the second list I can use the Set collection. However, I wonder if it is more optimal (in memory or computationally) to generate a filtering regular expression.
I program mainly in Java and Python and the question is theoretical.

Comment: You can construct such a pattern in any regex flavour that supports variable-length alternations by 1) escaping all input terms, 2) string-joining the resulting patterns with the alternation character (usually `|`) as delimiter, and then 3) wrapping the whole thing in anchors, eg. `^(...)$`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That won't always be the shortest though. That said, optimizing that is better done inside the regex engine than on the way in. A number of regex implementations already do that.

Comment: I see that you've tagged this [theory]. Are you looking to *implement* such an algorithm? Or merely looking for an explanation of why such an algorithm exists? (Also, are you using "regular expression" in the computer science sense, or are you talking about a specific implementation of regexes? An example will help clarify that.)

Comment: You could almost certainly do it by building a [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) and then generating the regex from that. As I recall, there are known methods for generating an optimum suffix tree.

Comment: @JimMischel Some strings are better combined through a common prefix, others through a common suffix, rarely you can combine both ways when there is a common middle and lots of suffix/prefix pairs are present.  How many of these do we try?

Comment: @btilly Perhaps you're right. Maybe something like the Aho-Corasick trie? But I don't know if that's optimum. It *sounds like* the problem could be solved with some form of suffix automaton, but I don't really have the time to puzzle it out and prove myself right or wrong.

Comment: Definitely possible to find the smallest [DAWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) efficiently. Regex I believe is NP-hard.

Comment: A random thought: How about longest common subsequence among all strings?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Interesting. I figured if you could reduce it to a DAWG, then the regex would just be a text representation of the finite state machine. I'll have to study that to see where I went wrong.

Comment: @JimMischel As btilly observes, if we're talking about standard regexes (empty, symbol, concat regex regex, union regex regex; no star since it would match too much), they have to be constructed in a series-parallel fashion, whereas a DAWG can have N-shaped substructures. As an example, ((A|a)(B|b))|((A|a)(C|c))|((D|d)(C|c)): we could choose to factor the first two alternatives, or the last two alternatives, but with a regex, we can't do both. With a DAWG, we can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes-ish.   Consult *Compilers Principles, Techniques and Tools* chapter on lexical analysis for a definitive reference, but basically you build a stylized state machine where each state represents a prefix of a subset of your strings, and a transition for each character to the next state.
If a given state (prefix) is the entirety of a string it could be considered accepted.

Minus the time to construct the state machine; this runs in *O(n)* for an arbitrary list of strings, because it never has to backtrack.

Comment: The states from this wind up matching the nodes of a Trie. But if the strings have a long shared suffix, that might give a shorter regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this question as [theory], haven't mentioned a specific flavor of [regex], and ask only if an algorithm exists, I'm going to take you at your word that you are literally asking if such an algorithm exists — in essence, that this is a computer science question rather than strictly a programming question.

If so, then the answer is: yes!

To see why, consider the following facts:

1. For any finite alphabet and any finite length, we can straightforwardly generate all strings of that length containing only characters in that alphabet.
2. There certainly exists a regular expression that matches exactly the strings in our list. For example, if the list is [`abc`,`def`,`ghi`], then one such regular expression is `abc+def+ghi`.

   - Note that, per the convention in computer science, I'm using `+` to denote alternation — equivalent to `|` in Perl-like regular expressions.
   - Caveat: I'm assuming that our input is a *non-empty* list of strings. Every regular expression matches at least one string, so if our input is an *empty* list, then there's no solution. But we can easily detect that case upfront, and return an error.
3. Any such regular expression will be a string containing only characters from the list of strings, plus possibly the special characters `+`, `(`, and `)`.

   - Note that I'm not worrying about the possibility that our input might contain these special characters; we can always handle that sort of case by using different/new/unique special characters in place of `+`, `(`, and `)`.
   - Regular expressions can also have the special character `*`, but *our* regular expression won't, because any regular expression containing `*` necessarily matches infinitely many strings, so can't satisfy our criterion.
   - We know that the expression won't contain any other character that isn't in any of these strings, because then it would match at least one string that isn't in the list.
4. For any string containing only those characters, we can straightforwardly check if it's a valid regular expression.
5. For any regular expression containing only those characters, we can fairly straightforwardly generate the list of strings that that regular expression matches. (Since the regular expression doesn't contain `*`, that list will be finite.)
6. Given two finite lists of strings, we can straightforwardly check if they contain the same strings.

. . . and, you probably see where I'm going with this. For each integer *n*, we generate all strings of length *n* containing only characters from the above-described alphabet, and for each such string, we check if it's a valid regular expression that matches exactly the right set of strings. We know that we'll find such a regular expression, and once we do, we'll have our answer.

Comment: Nice, but I think you could more briefly say: Yes, because at least one solution exists, so a smallest solution must exist.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks! My sense from the question is that the OP already assumed that there's a smallest solution, but didn't see how to go from "there's a smallest solution" to "we can find it". The approach in this answer is second nature to CS types, but not immediately intuitive to people who are used to thinking of an algorithm as a thing you might genuinely choose to implement.